# Convergence of sequences in product of normed vector spaces yields convergent sequences in the respective normed vector spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Let's say I have two normed vector spaces $X$ and $Y$ with norms $|| \cdot ||_X$ and $|| \cdot ||_Y$. Suppose I have a sequence $\left((x_n, y_n)\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq X \times Y$ which converges to $(x, y) \in X \times Y$, does it then follow that $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$? $(*)$

This seems natural however there isn't a natural/canonical norm on $X \times Y$, there are a whole family of norms that we can usually use, namely for $(a, b) \in X \times Y$ we have $$||(a, b)||_p = \begin{cases}
\left(||a||_X^p + ||b||_Y^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}, \ \ \text{if } 1 \leq p < \infty \\
\operatorname{max}\{a, b\} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{if } p = \infty \\
\end{cases} $$

which yields a norm on $X \times Y$ for each $p$. So does $(*)$ happen in all of these norms, i.e. is it true that no matter which norm on $X \times Y$ we have, if we have a sequence $\left((x_n, y_n)\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq X \times Y$ which converges to $(x, y) \in X \times Y$, then it follows that $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$?

If not then in which of these norms does the nice convergence property $(*)$ hold?

Answer (score 0):

See page 89 of Dunford-Scwartz, "Linear Operators, Part I." You can use either of the norms, each yields the product topology.